# LdapConnection Bind() always fails over SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I need to query some information with Active Directory that is only accessible when authenticated over SSL. I can make anonymous connections without issue, but I always get an "LDAP server is unavailable error" when trying to use SSL. There's a lot of forum topics about this, and I've reviewed them but have not found a solution. This code is an ASP.NET MVC app being run on IIS Express.

```
LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection("ldap.xxx.com:636/OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx");
                    //conn.AutoBind = false;
                    conn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                    conn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic; //Tried with Negotiate as well
                    conn.Credential = new NetworkCredential(@"domain\user", "userPW", "domain");
                    conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    conn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((dev, cer) => true);
                    //conn.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
                    conn.Bind();
```

I use that container string with a PrincipalContext to validate the credentials for this account, that validation is successful (that takes place before this code). The container places me into the correct node and the account credentials are a match. Which is why this error puzzles me. Protocol version is correct as well. I've set the verifycert callback to return true regardless of the certificate.

The error is being thrown on the first line, if I remove the container it creates the connection, but then hangs indefinitely when I call .Bind(). If I specify the domain after the connection is made, the "unavailable error" is thrown on .Bind(). I don't understand why it fails with the container because it works when passed in with a PrincipalContext.

Thank you for any help.